# White floaties at the top of each bottle

Tags: beer, hops

This is my first time brewing a batch of beer. At the top of each bottle there is a tiny amount of little while floaty things. The rest is super clear.

I've tried to get a photo of the floaties, there's a big one in the center with a couple tiny ones to the left of it.

There doesn't appear to be a white film on top, more just a bunch of little white "fibres".

Every bottle looks like this so my big Q, can/should I drink it if it smells/tastes ok?

It was made from this kit http://www.muntonshomebrew.com/premium-pilsner/ with a handful of hops added in.

Thanks

[image: sweet floaties]

Comment: How did you sanitize your bottles? How fermentation went, what ABV / gravity it had at the end? How (and how long) you were lagering it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fungal (mold) to me. Could be from poor bottle sanitation or too much head space.

Were these bottle conditioned? If so I could just be floculant yeast.

Whatever it is, it's unlikely to be harmful for consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be live yeast still eating was your fermentation complete before you bottled if it was complete.then it could be a bad batch or the bottles may not been sanitized completely..

Comment: Pretty confident that the bottles were well sanitized. I'm wondering if it wasn't quite fermented when I bottled it. Ended up having a try last night and it tastes all right. No one went blind and everyone got a lil drunk so must be ok.